# Migration netflix feign in Springboot 1.x to openfeign in Springboot 2.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign

I try doing migration Springboot 1.x.y (Brussels-SR12) to 2.x.y. I use `FeignClients`

**I change Maven configuration:**

```
<spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
```

so

```
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-openfeign</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
```

**I change all import:**

```
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.EnableFeignClients;

import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClient;
```

to

```
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;

import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
```

**I use this interface:**

```
@FeignClient(value = "COMPANY", fallbackFactory = CompanyClientFallbackFactory.class, configuration = FeignConfiguration.class)
public interface CompanyClient extends CompanyApi {
}
```

**When I run my JUnit tests (with spring context), i have this error now (not in Springboot 1.x.y and old netflix package):**

```
The bean 'COMPANY.FeignClientSpecification', defined in null, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in null and overriding is disabled.
```

**Full trace:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'COMPANY.FeignClientSpecification' defined in null: Cannot register bean definition [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientSpecification]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] for bean 'COMPANY.FeignClientSpecification': There is already [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientSpecification]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] bound.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:896)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientsRegistrar.registerClientConfiguration(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:355)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientsRegistrar.registerFeignClients(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:155)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientsRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:83)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably you have multiple `@FeignClient` definitions with the same name attribute.

Answer (score 20):

that's the solution from the [Feign documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#spring-cloud-feign-overriding-defaults):

> If we want to create multiple feign clients with the same name or url
> so that they would point to the same server but each with a different
> custom configuration then we have to use `contextId` attribute of the
> `@FeignClient` in order to avoid name collision of these configuration
> beans.
>
> ```
> @FeignClient(contextId = "fooClient", name = "stores", configuration = FooConfiguration.class)
> public interface FooClient {
>     //..
> }
>
> @FeignClient(contextId = "barClient", name = "stores", configuration = BarConfiguration.class)
> public interface BarClient {
>     //..
> }
> ```

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/pull/90/commits/82fa5181fdd2e23e7414521f468ecea88e17d157

Answer (score 8):

This can also occur if you accidentally have more than one @Configuration class annotated with @EnableFeignClients

Comment: This fixed it for me. But I still would like to have two separate configurations in different modules.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution but is it a **workaround**. Please see [@Alessandro Dionisi response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52850357/migration-netflix-feign-in-springboot-1-x-to-openfeign-in-springboot-2-x/54475670#54475670)

application.yml:

```
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
```

Comment: Yes, is a workaround but not a solution, thank you @AlessandroDionisi

Comment: this is absolutely workaround, you should think to rename your feignclients or seperate each other with different urls.

Comment: this workaround will lead you to more complicated problems because it masks problems with your beans

Comment: @Lu55, please see Alessandro Dionisi response

Answer (score 0):

mvn clean package fixed this error for me

Answer (score -3):

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

Comment: You copy/paste my answer but that's not a solution but a workaround